# Communication between pass and webservice

Tags: ios, web-services, passbook

I'm starting to develop services related to the Passbook and I can not establish communication between the webservice and pass.

I started by creating the file ". pkpass", ie, generating keys, adding pictures and customizing JSONs.
I managed to create the file and display the pass on my iPhone.

The problem is that the pass made ​​no interaction with my webservice.
I had to make a few tries to realize that Apple does not use the HTTP protocol for production environment only HTTPS.
My server is enabled to receive requests on HTTPS protocol, but my script is not allowed.
I am in doubt if this is the problem or is there something more that has to be done.

I obeyed all the communication protocol presented in Passbook Webservice Reference.
Someone has gone through a similar situation?

---

Ooops ...

I enabled the developer logs on my iPhone and found that the request is being sent, but it is not valid because of my HTTPS certificate server is considered unsafe.

Does anyone know how I can purchase a certificate free HTTPS?

Comment: Is the pass registering with your web service?  Perhaps you could post your pass.json or better still a link to a .pkpass bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you got it working. For your secondary question - you can get free SSL Certs from [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com)

Comment: Am not understanding the concept of how and where to store the data after i retrieve the data as JSON from my web service. Can you suggest any ref links for it